# Will treating minor infections with medication slow down or prevent anti body generation?

Tags: immune-system

My 2 yo son gets sick fairly often, as expected for his age. Since his immune system has yet to build antibodies against all the usual infections. I wonder if medicating minor infections is doing more harm than good, since it essentially robs his body of the opportunity to learn and remember this particular infection by building antibodies. From what I understand the body needs quite some time with an infection, until it develops immunity against it. Could cutting the infection short hinder this process?

Comment: By medications do you mean antibiotics or something else?

Comment: I mean any medication, capable of healing the infection. For example antibiotics or nasal drops against runny nose or even cough medication.

Comment: Most medications for the common cold and flu such as nasal drops, cough syrup or even paracetamol will not "cut the infection short". They only make the person feel better, they don't actually treat the underlying infection. The only medication that will have a large effect in "cutting the infection short" is antibiotics, and they only work for bacterial infections.